# Server Problem exporting SRL query from PHPmyadmin with top button

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to export an SQL result in phpmyadmin, and I used the top menu "Export", when I tryied to export as CSV nd than PDF, I had a strange message impossible to create the table "somenameintotheSQLdonotremebernow"...ok I quit, and I found the other button on the botton and it worked...

What that top Export button do exactly if you want to export an SQL query?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403864/export-and-import-mysql-databases

Comment: What filename did you use?

Comment: to make it clear I want to export only the query I made in the SQL editor... :)  filename  "aaa"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete error message, phpMyAdmin version number, and export settings you're trying to use, it's quite difficult to know what went wrong.

However, on any results page (including the "Browse" tab), there are three export buttons:

[image: Query results page]

The top one, in pink, as part of the regular navigation tabs, takes you to the table export page. This is a regular navigation feature and the page you're taken to isn't related to the current view. If you're on a database level page, this takes you to the database export page instead of the table export. From here, you would dump an entire table.

The second one, in orange, appears with the "With selected:" modifier, so it works with the rows you've selected with the checkbox in the current view. In my screenshot, that means only the "NICK STALLONE" record will be exported.

Lastly, in blue, is the "Query results operations" area. This works with the results of your query. In my example, I did a custom SQL query to select only actors whose first name is 'nick', so it will export all three of those records that are shown. You could use this from the "Browse" tab but there's no benefit over using the pink-highlighted Export link that's part of the navigation tabs. So to answer your question, this is the one you would use to export the results of a particular query; just look for the heading "Query results operations."